# Avoiding mold after machine backup

Tags: plumbing, basement, water-damage

My washing machine just backed up (drain pipe is clogged). Fortunately I was home and just bought a shopvac last weekend, but a lot of water got out. Also fortunately this is an unfinished basement, but I’m worried about two things.

It damaged the seal on the floors - I figure this is easy to fix and probably not an immediate concern?

[image: floor damage]

And my bigger concern is water got into two areas. One where the water line comes in which seems to have a hole that goes down into the soil (not sure if this is by design?)

[image: water line entry]

And another area that is inaccessible.

[image: Are not accessible]

Is there something I should spray in these areas to prevent mold build-up or should a dehumidifier be enough? The basement is generally very very dry - I wasn’t sure if a dehumidifier is even necessary, but I’m worried the inaccessible area will not dry out as fast as there is a lot of dirt, dust and other junk in there that looks like it can hold moisture.

Answer (score 1):

Drying it out will probably be the best but if you want to sanitize it I would use 3% hydrogen peroxide and water. Hydrogen peroxide doesent have the smell and will kill organics very well. Remember to always add acid to water (AAA).